# dependency error with spring framework 4.2.4 and spring-security-config

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

I am trying to create a security context with tokens as in the [Spring-Rest-Boilerplate](https://github.com/dhavaln/spring-rest-boilerplate), but adding the spring-security-config dependency results in the following error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration':
>   Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire method: public void
>   org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor,java.util.List)
>   throws java.lang.Exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression
>   parsing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'ignoredPathsWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter':
>   Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorController
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration$IgnoredPathsWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.errorController;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorController] is
>   defined: expected single matching bean but found 3:
>   dataColController,picturePostController,userController

This is my `pom.xml` file:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.springframework.samples</groupId>      
  <packaging>war</packaging>    
  <properties>

        <!-- Generic properties -->
        <tomcat.version>8.0.24</tomcat.version>

        <!--  Spring Boot Java Version -->
        <!--  <java.version>1.8</java.version> -->

        <!--  AWS Java Versions -->
        <java.version>1.7</java.version> 

        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <!-- Spring Latest: 4.2.4.-->
        <spring-framework.version>4.2.4.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>
        <spring-boot.version>1.3.2.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>            
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>

        <!-- Test -->
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
         <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>    
    </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->

        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId> 
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId> 
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version> 
        </dependency>    

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>             

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>

            <exclusions>
               <exclusion>
                  <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                  <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
            </exclusions> 

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>   

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </dependency> 

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
         <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>  
        </exclusions> 
        </dependency>       

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
            <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>    
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jasper-el</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>  
        </dependency>
```

Comment: You are using Spring Boot, then use Spring Boot. You are trying very hard (dependency wise) not to. Use the `spring-boot-starter-security` instead of Spring Security dependencies directly as well as the `spring-boot-starter-web` (which you already have) as such remove the spring and tomcat dependencies those will be managed by Spring Boot.

Comment: But if the objective is to deploy on Tomcat, there can't be any spring boot?

Comment: Where do I mention that you should remove all of spring-boot. I also suggest to read the spring boot reference guide on how to use the dependencies to create a deployable war.

Comment: Will do that, but I can inform you that using spring-boot-starter-security doesn't help

Comment: Have you actually read the stack trace? Apparently you decided that your controller must implement the `ErrorController` interface whereas only a single one is expected. Remove that interface.

Comment: That hasen't caused any problem until adding spring-security.I guess this mess of dependencies is a contributing factor to people abandoning Spring

Comment: The error clearly states that there are 3 dependencies of that bean, which might be triggered due that some other dependency being pulled in. This jar hell is why the starter projects and spring io platform is there. To prevent users to include incompatible dependencies (you get tested versions that work with all other dependencies in that line).